# Google Analytics: Compare same Metric with different filters

Tags: filter, google-analytics, metrics

I'd like to create a dashboard widget which compares two values:

- The total number of Events with a certain keyword in the Event Action (e.g. `foo`)
- The total number of events containing a more specific Event Action name (e.g. `foo-bar`)

Thus I have two filters on the same metric, and I want the values to be on the same graph. The default Timeline widget allows for comparing *two different metrics* with the *same* filters, but not the reverse.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I took a stab at an answer but as this is not code-related it might very well be closed as off-topic. Question about configuration should probably go to webmasters@stackexchange.com.

Comment: Good call, @EikePierstorff -- I'll look there and possibly vote to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Enter your filter ("event action contains foo"). The first line in the table will be the total for all events including "foo". The following lines will show all different events containing "foo" ("foo-bar", "koong-foo" etc).

Locate the line that has "foo-bar" as dimension value. Click the checkbox in front on the line. Click the "plot rows" button above the table. You will now have a line for the totals and in the same graph the line for the selected row (works for up to 4 rows at a time).